# Hide rows that do not contain a value (negative logic)

Tags: excel

I have been working through this problem. I want to hide all cells that do not contain a text value in a cell. "C8" holds a value which can change as a function of a pull down menu.

I want to leave the rows that contain the "C8" value, and hide all others. I can get it to work as long as I do not use a specific cell with a specific content (C8), when I add the variable of a certain cell value, the macro will not run.

Why won't it accept the specific cell content ?

```
Sub Hide_Based_upon_Selection()
Dim r As Long
For r = 9 To 37
If Range("C8").Value <> "PS" Then
    Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If

If Range("C8").Value <> "VP" Then
    Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
           Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Same question as on SuperUser, in which column do we look in the rows for the value?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Sub Hide_Based_upon_Selection()
Dim r As Long

For r = 9 To 37
    ActiveSheet.Rows(r).Hidden = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "K") <> ActiveSheet.Range("C8")
Next r

End Sub
```

it will hide the row if the value in K is not equal to C8